# Refer by address in range function

Tags: go

I have a `OuterStruct` structure defined as given below. I am using the function to initialize the `OuterStruct -> InnerStruct` values `Name and Var1` in `setup1()` and `Var1` in `setup2()`.

The value assigned in setup2() is `nil` always because it is referring it by value. How to use refer my address here ?

```
type InnerStruct struct {
    Name  string
    Var1  *api.Var1
    Var2  *ap1.Var2
}

type OuterStruct struct {
    opName   string
    MyData   []InnerStruct
    LogDir   string
}

func (obj *OuterStruct) Setup2() {
    for _, innerObj := range obj.InnerStruct {   // Here is the prob becuase of using refer by value
        innerObj.Var2 = callToPopulateValue()
    }
}

func Setup1() {
    innerStructList := []InnerStruct

    myStruct := InnerStruct{}
    myStruct.Name = "name1"
    myStruct.Var1 = callToPopulateValue()
    innerStructList = append(innerStructList, myStruct)

    finalStruct = &OuterStruct {
        opName: "structName",
        MyData: innerStructList,
        LogDir: "/path/for/my/logs",
    }

    finalStruct.Setup2()
}
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal, verifiable and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code given won't even compile (e.g. it references `obj.InnerStruct` when the field is `obj.MyData`). Test your sample code before posting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access by address, but you can get the index from `range` instead, and assign to the slice directly:

```
    for i := range obj.MyData {
        obj.MyData[i].Var2 = callToPopulateValue()
    }
```

Alternately, you can just use a slice of pointer values:

```
type OuterStruct struct {
    opName   string
    MyDAta   []*InnerStruct
    LogDir   string
}

func (obj *OuterStruct) Setup2() {
    for _, innerObj := range obj.MyData {
        innerObj.Var2 = callToPopulateValue()
    }
}
```